# Using Timeline Support with "reverse" in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, reverse

I want to reverse a small space in my video that doesn't seem like Timeline editing doesn't support that
I tried to use the following command

```
ffmpeg -y -i "{input}. *" -filter_complex "reverse = enable = 'gte (t, 3)': preset = cross_process" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b: v 1200k -acodec libmp3lame -b: a 128k -ar 44100 -preset superfast "{output} .mp4"
```

Look forward to the help . thank you

Comment: So you want timestamp 0-3 to play normally, then reverse from 3-0?

Comment: right . Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the reverse/areverse and concat [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).

### Video only

```
ffmpeg -t 3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse[rev];[0:v][rev]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

### Video and audio

```
ffmpeg -t 3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse[rev];[0:a]areverse[arev];[0:v][0:a][rev][arev]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Comment: thank you . but i want to loop it as continuous. 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0 ......Your plan has had 1 iteration but it will output 1 video 6s = 0 3

Comment: @Ffmpeg That requirement should have been clearly stated in the question. Before I make a new answer what are your other requirements?